# Buying a 3rd PS4 and PS+?

Tags: playstation-plus

I currently have 2 PS4's one in my Living room and one in my youngest kids room.  I'm considering getting a third PS4 for my oldest son, but I'm not sure how we can use my PS+ across all 3 so we can all play together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only activate one PS4 as the primary system for an account. To have PSN+ on all three systems with all of the benefits (free games you can play multi-player, etc...), you'll need three PSN+ accounts (one for each system).

From Sony's [PS4 Activation Guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html)

> You can activate the system as your primary PS4™ system with your Sony Entertainment Network account. By activating the system, the following actions can be performed:
>
> - Anyone who uses your primary PS4™ system can enjoy applications you purchase from PlayStation®Store.
> - Anyone who uses your primary PS4™ system can enjoy numerous benefits if you subscribe to PlayStation®Plus.
> - You can automatically download to the PS4™ system content you pre-ordered, or content purchased on PlayStation®App.
> - You can connect to the PS4™ system from a PS Vita system via the Internet using Remote Play.
> - Anyone who uses your primary PS4™ system can enjoy themes that you purchase from PlayStation®Store.
>
>   - You can activate only 1 PS4™ system per account.
>   - If a user activates a system with his or her account, other users on the system can use applications and enjoy some PlayStation®Plus benefits from that account, even if that user is not logged in.
>   - To enjoy certain PlayStation®Plus benefits, you must subscribe to the service. For details, refer to the website for your country or region.